# What is wrong in this binding?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I have an angular ui-grid in which data is displayed and in every row there is an "Edit" and "Delete" button. When the user clicks on the "Edit" then a modal window is displayed and the fields are populated and the user can edit the data. This is the user scenario I have. When the user clicks on the "Edit" button I pass through the id value and when angular creates the modal window I query the data from the server.

As you can see in the html the controller is not bound because it is managed by another controller. If it would be bound here then it would be called twice.

The fields are populated properly and when I change something in it and I want to save it then breeze says that nothing has changed in the entity and the log in the save method gives back the original values of the entity.

I assume something is wrong with the data binding but I don't know what.

According to the pluralsight video and breeze's documentation breeze tracks the changes in the entity.

What I'm doing wrong?
The form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="editModuleModalForm">

    <legend>Edit module</legend>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Module name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Module name here..."
                   data-ng-model="vm.sysmodule.name"
                   data-z-validate />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Module Sort number</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Module sort number"
                   data-ng-model="vm.sysmodule.sortNo"
                   data-z-validate />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Route</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text"
                   placeholder="Module route comes here..."
                   data-ng-model="vm.sysmodule.route"
                   value="vm.sysmodule.route"
                   data-z-validate />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="vm.save()">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>


</form>
```

Angular controller for the form

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = 'editModuleController';

    angular
        .module('dilibApp')
        .controller(controllerId, ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'selectedModuleId', 'common', 'datacontext', editModuleController]);

    function editModuleController($scope, $modalInstance, selectedModuleId, common, datacontext) {

        /* jshint validthis:true */
        var vm = this;
        vm.title = 'editModule';
        vm.sysmodule = undefined;
        vm.cancel = cancel;
        vm.save = save;

        activate();

        function activate() {
            onDestroy();
            common.activateController([getModulePropertiesToBeEdited()], controllerId);
        }

        function getModulePropertiesToBeEdited() {
            return datacontext.sysmodule.getById(selectedModuleId)
                .then(function (result) {
                    vm.sysmodule = result[0];
                });
        }

        function onDestroy() {
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                datacontext.cancel();
            });
        }

        function cancel() {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        }

        function save() {
            console.log(vm.sysmodule);
            if (datacontext.hasChanges) {
                datacontext.saveChanges();
                console.log('Changes are saved!');
            } else {
                console.log('There are no changes to be saved!');
            }

            $modalInstance.close();
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the binding. The root if the problem is that the datacontext doesn't have hasChanges method due to that the breeze's entityManager is wrapped in it. I had to rework the code a little bit, rethinking the responsibilities and it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with the binding. The root if the problem is that the datacontext doesn't have hasChanges method due to that the breeze's entityManager is wrapped in it. I had to rework the code a little bit, rethinking the responsibilities and it is working now.